# UIWebview in iPad

Tags: ipad, uiwebview

1) I load a URL in UIWebview ,which has some images .I want to enable the option,"save photo" which appears when you long-press the images in webview.Currently this option is available in Safari Browser.But I couldn't find any option in UIwebView class, And UIdataDetectorType struct dont have option for images (as of my knowledge.)

So how do I have this in my APP?

2) when I open some PDFs in webview ,I want to provide an option to open the pdf in iBooks.
How to do?

Thanks in advance.

GopiKrishnAn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be 2 separate questions.

1/ Read this blog post by iCab's author: [Customize the contextual menu of UIWebView](http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/07/11/customize-the-contextual-menu-of-uiwebview/). It shows you exactly how to implement long press detection in a UIWebView.

As a bonus, his blog is a wealth of useful information about UIWebView.

2/ You need to work with `UIDocumentInteractionController`. As its initialization method (`+ (UIDocumentInteractionController *)interactionControllerWithURL:(NSURL *)url`) only works with a local URL, I guess you need to download the PDF and save it somewhere before you are able to provide such options.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anh! your answer received gratefully.